# Getting https on aws assigned loadbalancer dns?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

Is it possible to get https to work on the automatically assigned DNS you get from the aws load balancer when you deploy a service like so:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name:  gateway-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app:  gateway
  type:  LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name:  gateway-svc
    port:  80
    targetPort:  4000
```

I know you can use annotations and something like this:

```
metadata:
  name:  gateway-svc
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:region:<NUMBER>:certificate/c556ca29-ddbe-4983-b01b-ff7e9f2708ba
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
```

But registering the auto assigned dns that is something like `http://<NUMBERS>-<NUMBERS>.<REGION>.elb.amazonaws.com/` is too long for the ACM.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

> But registering the auto assigned dns that is something like
> http://-..elb.amazonaws.com/ is too long for
> the ACM.

Why are you looking forward to get the ACM cert for that domain ?

**ACM** provides the **wildcard** certificate and you can that for your domain.

While for adding the **entry** into DNS like **route53**

you should checkout the **external DNS**

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns#running-locally
If you domain if **xyz.com** you can get the ***.xyz.com** and use that everywhere as it's the wild card and attach to any **LB** service.